# Postgres doesn't have hstore extension

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to run the following command but i threw me any error.

```
template1=# CREATE EXTENSION hstore

ERROR: could not open extension control file "usr/share/postgreesql/9.2/extension/hstore.control": No such file or directory
```

It seems like I need to download the postgres-devel packages, but I don't know exactly what I am missing. I installed my postgres with this command so I thought everything I need would be included together.

```
sudo apt-get install postgres-9.2
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The *hstore* extension, as well as many other extensions such as *cube*, *fuzzystrmatch*, *uuid-ossp*, etc., are packaged in `postgresql-contrib`, which you can install for your PostgreSQL version using:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.2
```

On a standard Ubuntu install,

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

will install PostgreSQL with its contributed extensions.